# Stream Audio Via TCP in UE4

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am trying to build a Virtual Assistant in UE4. I need to somehow send my response from DialogFlow to UE4 for use in the Oculus Lipsync Plugin.

Basically, I have 3 media options for the response: 
-16-Bit Linear PCM
-mp3
-Ogg Opus

I have a TCP Server and Client connection set up between a Python Script and UE4, so I can send data to and from easily.
I have my sequencing correct so one script waits for the full Byte Array to be sent via the socket etc.

Basically, I want to send the responses to each Query the user sends to DialogFlow INTO UE4 Via my TCP Socket, and be able to play and access that Audio within UE4.
I need to somehow stream the response from DialogFlow into UE4 as it gives me the responses.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? I'm just trying to stream in Audio for use within UE4 and I am really struggling to get it working. Very annoying as this is the last piece of the puzzle I need to finish....

Please let me know if you have any advice or help you can offer!

Comment: if you have server and client in both side of your program you can post messages bidirectional. another thing for streaming audio and video usually using `RTP` instead of `TCP`